# Nginx doesn't load css on Asp.net core in raspberry

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, nginx

First of all, thanks for reading my thread. Second, sorry for my English.

I'm trying to run an Asp.net core application in a raspberry but still facing some problems when proxying with nginx.

Basically I follow these tutorials to configure my workplace and export my project to arm, the only difference is that I've created a MVC application instead a simple Hello World:

http://www.protosystem.net/blog/aspnet-core-on-raspberry-pi/
http://www.protosystem.net/blog/aspnet-core-hello-world-on-raspberry-pi/

The problem starts when I execute the app. For default, it runs on port 5000, but when nginx do the proxy for port 80 it doesn't load the css.min, javascrip files and the Home directory according to the image below:

[image: On the port 5000]

[image: Port 80]

Follow the nginx configuration below:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
          listen [::]:80 default_server;

          root /www/mywebsite;

          index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

          server_name _;


            location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }}
```

Comment: Try removing the `try_files`. To me (might be wrong) it seems like you are saying pass everything to the proxy but then use try files which looks for the file in the file system. When not found it returns a 404.

Comment: It worked!
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment I would suggest removing the `try_files` directive like so:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    root /www/mywebsite;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }}
}
```